# VOIP wake up in iOS4

Tags: stream, voip, ios4

has anyone gotten VIOP sockets to wake up the app on receipt of new data?
I have been able to do the following: 
set plist flag to voip
set the streams as voip type

the sockets remain open when the application moves into the background but messages are not processed. 
According to apple the correct behaviour is 
" If new data arrives while your application is suspended, the system wakes up your application so that it can process the data. In the case of an incoming phone call, your application would typically alert the user immediately using a local notification. For other noncritical data, or if the user ignores the call, the system returns your application to the suspended state when it finishes processing the data."

anyone able to get that to work?

Comment: better off asking in the Apple Developer forums.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the streams before opening them ?
It won't work unless you do so.